# How to extract all noun phrases in French Sentences with Spacy(Python)

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

I am trying to extract all the noun phrases from French sentences using Spacy. My code appears not to be working well in all the cases I tried. For example,

```
    nlp = spacy.load("fr_core_news_sm")
    doc = nlp("Il y a plusieurs petits restaurants dans cette ville.")
    for chunk in doc.noun_chunks:
      print(chunk)
```

returns

`[Il y a plusieurs petits restaurants dans cette ville.]` as the noun phrase, this appears to be incorrect as the noun phrase here is `petits restaurants dans cette ville`.

When I tried other sets of phrases, such as `J'ai trouvé une jolie petite chambre.`, it returned 3 phrases, `[J' , une jolie, petite chambre]` which seems not to be correct also

Lastly, with `Les deux dernières semaines, il était à Paris..` it returned `[Les deux dernières semaines, il]` which appears to be correct.

I would appreciate any help or guidance on how to ensure the code works correctly for the first two examples also.

Comment: I'm afraid that this is the pre-trained model's prediction: you can't change it, weights are frozen. What exactly are you asking for?

Comment: the model appears no to be working correctly. Is there anything I can do in my code to make it perform better(correctly identify NPs)?

Answer (score 1):

First try updating your version of SpaCy

```
pip install spacy --upgrade
```

Change your model from small `fr_core_news_sm` to a larger one such as `fr_core_news_lg`

To install:

```
-python -m spacy download fr_core_news_lg
```

or directly pip install from SpaCy's model repository e.g.

```
pip install https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases/download/fr_core_news_lg-2.3.0/fr_core_news_lg-2.3.0.tar.gz
```

Larger models typically have better accuracy on most NLP tasks.